# Datetime C#: Subtracting time off of exsisting time

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

I have a DateTime variable set to give me the time now. I want to adjust the value off the time now to 3 seconds before. Let me give you an example:

CurrentTime = 2/3/2014 12:59:49 PM

I want CurrentTime = 2/3/2014 12:59:46 PM

What can I do get this result and keep the variable with type DateTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substract any given time span by adding seconds/minutes/hours/days/etc from DateTime

```
DateTime before = CurrentTime.AddSeconds(-3);
```

Code based on your example (you substracted 3 seconds from time)

Answer (score 3):

```
var newTime = CurrentTime - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3.0);
```

Based on the example you're showing it seems that you actually want the time 3 seconds before, not 3 milliseconds. If so, just change it to

```
var newTime = CurrentTime - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0);
```

and if you want to change the value of CurrentTime simply do `CurrentTime =`
followed by either of the previous statements.

Comment: Yes, sorry I edited it I meant 3 seconds. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 2):

You can check MSDN is `DateTime` have something  like [AddMilliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmilliseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use it

```
 CurrentTime = CurrentTime.AddMilliseconds(-3);
```

Note that `DateTime` is immutable value type, so you need to re-assign `CurrentTime` to result of `AddMilliseconds` (which generates *new instances* of `DateTime`).